# How can I count all dupe values in a JSON collection?

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, underscore.js

I would like to count all the companies in the following JSON string. I was first planning on doing it manually with loops but it seems like this is a good chance for me to learn to use map/reduce... How can return something that returns `{company: 2}`?

```
[
  {
    _id: '123',
    company: 'Acme'
  }
  {
    _id: '123',
    company: 'Innatrode'
  }
  {
    _id: '123',
    company: 'Acme'
  }
]
```

Comment: Question is not very clear as such. Do you want the number of unique company names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the number of unique company names, then

1. use [`_.pluck`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to get the `company` attribute out of the list of company objects
2. Find the unique values out of them with [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq), which will return an array.
3. Compose a new object with the key `com

   ```
   console.log({company: _.uniq(_.pluck(companies, "company")).length});
   # { company: 2 }
   ```